# Redireccionar al home si no es admin

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

tengo que redireccionar al home ("/") si el usuario "Admin" quiere ingresar a /contacto
la pregunta es: cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo? yo lo hice con un useEffect que funciona, pero si hay una mejor forma de optimizarlo lo hago.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si pudieras pasar el código de la imagen, usando la opción `{} ejemplo de código` en la pregunta. Las preguntas con dicho formato son preferidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Deberías pasarte por [ask] y realizar el [tour]. Luego [edit] tu pregunta

Comment: Podrías crear un componente de tipo `PrivateRoute` que se encargue de dar el acceso a los perfiles o roles que corresponden.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando la version 6 de React Router Dom esta forma tambien funciona:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);

  return (
<HashRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route
          path="/contact"
          element={!isAdmin ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <ContactPage />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede crear un componente personalizado `PrivateRoute` que se encargue de otorgar acceso o denegar el mismo según se requiera.

```
/**
 * Private Routes
 *
 * This is a higher order component (HOC) for all routes defined as privates
 * in the application.
 */

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const isLogin = () => true

export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    // Shows the component only when the user is authenticated
    // otherwise, redirect to the path/signin.
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isLogin() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/signin' />
      }
    />
  )
}

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
}
```

### Usage

```
export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
      <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

Lo anterior es válido para v4 y v5 desconozco si habrá cambiado algo en v6.